# Jasmine JavaScript test - wait for a function test to finish

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, jasmine, automated-tests

I am trying out Jasmine to automate my JavaScript testing. I just can't find info about one thing (here are steps I want to do):

1. Login to a service. (returns SUCCESS or FAILED)
2. Establish a connection to a server. (returns SUCCESS or FAILED)
3. Make a test SIP call. (returns SUCCESS or FAILED)

Based on SUCCESS/FAILED, my Spec (scenario) fails or passes.

The problem in testing these 3 things: it takes time to do each, especially number 3. So far I have tried Jasmine and can'd figure out how to do a sequential tests like that, so each step (test) has to finish for next one to start. Maybe there is a better framework to do that? I am testing just JavasScript, not interface (buttons, text fields, etc.).

Here is a basic scenario I have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.5.2</title>

    <!-- voxImplant stuff-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.voximplant.com/voximplant.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine_favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine.css">

    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jasmine-2.5.2/boot.js"></script>

    <!-- include source files here... -->
    <script src="src/voximp_src.js"></script>    


    <!-- include spec files here... -->
    <script src="spec/voximp_spec.js"></script>

</head>

<body>     
</body>

</html>
```

```js
// Make a test call to play MP3
describe("[VoxEngine Basic Call Test]", function () {
    it('does something', function (done) {
        VoxEngine.Login_to_a_service()
            .then(VoxEngine.Establish_a_connection)
            .then(VoxEngine.Make_a_test_call)
            .then(function () {
                expect(1).toEqual("SUCCESS");
                done();
            })
            .catch(fail)
    });    
});
```

```js
window.VoxEngine = {
    Login_to_a_service: function () {        
        // Sleep
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        while (new Date().getTime() < now + 2000) { console.log("Login processing"); }

        console.log("Login done");
        return "SUCCESS";
    },

    Establish_a_connection: function () {
        // Sleep
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        while (new Date().getTime() < now + 2000) { console.log("Connection processing"); }

        console.log("Connection done");
        return "SUCCESS";
    },

    Make_a_test_call: function () {
        // Sleep
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        while (new Date().getTime() < now + 2000) { console.log("Call processing"); }

        console.log("call failed");
        return "FAIL";
    }
}
```

[Result for this template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaFCL.png)

So basically, I need to make sure they run one after another and the next one runs after previous one has finished. Let's say, Make-A-Test-Call has finished and then it tests if Connection-To-The-Server-Closed succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you acquire the `done` argument in your test case and call it when an async task is complete:

```
it('does something', function(done) {
    Login_to_a_service()
        .then(Establish_a_connection)
        .then(Make_a_test_call)
        .then(function() {
           expect(1).toBe(1); // or something that makes more sense...
           done();
        })
        .catch(fail)
});
```

Docs: https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I am 100% new to any WebDev stuff. Could you please elaborate on this a bit more?

Comment: @YuriyL: sure, but I have to know what part didn't you understand.

Comment: Sorry! I have edited my post. Please see what I have there.

Comment: So basically, I need to make sure they run one after another and next one runs after previous one has finished. Make a test call finished and then it tests if connection to the server has been terminated correctly.

Comment: @YuriyL: I guess `voxInit`, `voxConnect` etc don't simply return "success", they do some actual work. Can you share how these functions are actually called?

Comment: This is an empty template I have. I am still have to populate them. Is there a way, for example, to make sure they are ran one after another ? I am trying to understand how to do it. then I will try to put some code in each.

Comment: Your test case already runs these functions in order, provided they are synchronous. If they are not, then you have to use promises like I posted.

Comment: Hey, I have modified code snippets to match the code you provided. Is that the correct way? This is just a template.

Comment: No, `while(date....)` is not how async javascript works. Async functions should either accept a callback or return a promise.